# How to simulate network delay on android emulator?

Tags: android

For example:

sending "A" from app to sever takes 5 seconds.
Sever responds with "B" which takes 15 seconds to arrive at the app.
In adb, we can add a network delay of 5000 and delay only the outgoing traffic for 5 seconds but how can I delay the incoming traffic for 15 seconds?

Answer (score 4):

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#netdelay shows how to pass command line arguments to the emulator in order to set network delay times. E.g.

```
emulator -netdelay gprs
```

or

```
emulator -netdelay 20000
```

which sets the round-trip delay to 20 seconds.

Usually the app only sees the total round-trip delay and doesn't notice if the request delay was different than the response delay. It might make a difference if client-server clock skew matters, or if other clients are also requesting changes to shared data, but the emulator doesn't provide a way to simulate that.